# Compare two XML files using Windows batch

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file which reads an identical XML files stored in two different locations and compares whether their build version is the same or not using the build tag in the xmls file.The batch code is..

Batch code is..

```
 @echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "build=" 
set "build1="
set "ans=version same"
set "wrong=version not same"
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a %%b in (
    'find /i "<Build>" ^< "C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\piller-uniblock\master.xml" "C:\piller-uniblock\master.xml" '
) do set "build=%%a" "build1=%%b"

IF "%build%"=="%build1%" echo %ans%
 else echo %wrong%
```

I'm trying to store the value of build tag of the two xml files in 2 variables, then compare them.If they are same then it prints "same" else "not same" through variables.

The XML file stored at two different locations which I'm trying to read is

master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CDMDataXML xmlns="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema CDMLoaderXMLSchema.xsd">
<CDMDataVersion>
    <Major>1</Major>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
    <Build>50</Build>
    <Delimiter>.</Delimiter>
</CDMDataVersion>
```

The error message I'm getting is..

[image: error1]

I can't understand where I'm making a mistake in this code.Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` the two files, filter with `find` to get only the `<build>` lines and depending on which variable contains data, assign the retrieved information to one or the other

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "build=" 
    set "build1="

    set "ans=version same"
    set "wrong=version not same"

    for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('
        2^>nul type "C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\piller-uniblock\master.xml"
                    "C:\piller-uniblock\master.xml"
        ^| find /i "<Build>" 
    ') do if not defined build ( set "build=%%a" ) else ( set "build1=%%a" )

    IF "%build%"=="%build1%" ( echo %ans% ) else echo %wrong%
```

Answer (score 0):

you error is here `for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a %%b`

first your are taking only the third token so %%b will never be set.
Then you dont have to specify %%b even if you want more than one token that means :
(say you want to get the third and fourth tokens) you can write :

`for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=<>" %%a in ... do echo %%a %%b` (%%b will be automatically populated with the 4th token)